# How to add fields to a tree view with default values on button click?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I add a button that open a new wizard, this last is contain only one field is number , that's number is the number of fields that i want to creat on my tree notebook tree view with default value

for example if i type 20 , thene whene i submit should i get 20 entries in the tree view

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean but when i submit I get 20 entries in the view you mean 20 line in the tree view?!! is so what will be the values of article field in every line?!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is a one2many field. One2many fields are linked to your model by specifying the record id number in a field that you specify when you define the many2one field.

For example:

```py
child_ids = fields.One2many('child.model.name', 'parent_id', 'Child Records')
```

So when you create a new line using the one2many field, a new record is created of model "child.model.name" and the parent_id field is set to the id of the current record.

So to create a number of empty lines in your form, all you have to do is create records with the "parent_id" field set to the originating records id.

Firstly, you will need to pass the originating record's id to the wizard, which you would do in the button definition:

```
<button name="%(wizard_action)d"
    string="Wizard Button"
    type="action"
    context="{'default_source_record_id': active_id}" />
```

You will need a field called "source_record_id" in your wizard, which will be a many2one field with the same model that you are calling it from, and you will need to have that field in your wizard view, but you can make it invisible if you want.

In the code you're calling from the wizard, you will create a loop to call the create method on the "child.model.name" model to create that number of empty records. It would look something like this:

```py
iterations = self.nombre

for i in range(iterations):
    self.env['child.model.name'].create({
        'parent_id': self.source_record_id.id
    })
```

That will create the empty records and they will be displayed in your one2many field.

Comment: Thank you, can you look to my code and tell me where is the problem please

Comment: @Mahmoud you didn't mention what error or issue you're facing but now that I look at it the for loop should be for values in range(numbers)

Comment: yeah I add the for values in range(numbers)  but no result on tree view

Comment: @Mahmoud the line in your XML `context="{'default_source_record_id': active_id}"/>` is passing the id number of the active record to the field `source_record_id` in your wizard. You need to make sure your wizard has a field called `source_record_id` which is a Many2one field with the same model of the parent record to collect that value. Then you need to make sure that you're including that field when you create the new records, because that is how Odoo links the line to the parent model. In your One2many field you specified the model of the lines, and the field that refers to the parent.

Comment: thank you but I don't understand, can you give me a code example or more details, please

Answer (score 0):

Here is a capture of the model :
[image]
Look to my code :

```
@api.multi
def creat_fields(self):
    numbers = self.w_qtt
    for values in numbers:
        # self.env['sale.order.line'].create(lignes_vales)
        self.env['sale.order.line'].create({
            'contrat_name_id': self.w_contrat_name,
            'contrat_lignes_id' : self.w_contrat_line,
            'product_id' : self.w_product_name,
            'bons_po' : self.w_po_number,
            'product_uom_qty' : 1,
            'price_unit' : self.w_prix,
        })
```

and on the xml :

```
 <footer>
      <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
      <button 
           name="creat_fields" 
           string="Enregistrer" 
           class="oe_highlight" 
           context="{'default_source_record_id': active_id}"/>
</footer>
```